# Ordering values across different groups in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to order values of different cars across different regions, as an example. Following is the sample data set.

```
import pandas as pd

region = ['east','west', 'central', 'east', 'west', 'central', 'east', 'west', 'central']
automobile = ['bmw', 'bmw', 'bmw', 'tesla', 'tesla', 'tesla', 'lucid', 'lucid', 'lucid']
price = [250, 350, 300, 500, 550, 575, 950, 900, 850]
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'region':region,
                        'automobile':automobile,
                        'price':price} )
display(df_test)
```

I would like to make sure that for each automobile, the price across three reqions is synchronized such
that East <= Central <= West (as they are for BMW). If they are not sync'd', price on the East should be
the base price. Eg. for Lucid, its price in Central should be 950 and then in West should be 950 as well. For Testla,
the price in West needs to be raised to match Central i.e. 575.

I think I should use GROUPBY but just cant make any progress. I imagine that a function like ffill() could be used after pivoting the data, but I hope there is a simpler solution.

Any help would appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cummax` with `groupby`, but you need to sort your data in the correct order with categorical dtype:

```
# assign the order for the regions
df_test['region'] = pd.Categorical(df_test['region'], ordered=True, categories=['east','central', 'west'])

df['price'] = (df_test.sort_values(['automobile','region'])    # sort data in the correct order
                      .groupby('automobile')['price'].cummax() # use cummax to correct the values
        
              )
```

Output:

```
    region automobile  price
0     east        bmw    250
1     west        bmw    350
2  central        bmw    300
3     east      tesla    500
4     west      tesla    575
5  central      tesla    575
6     east      lucid    950
7     west      lucid    950
8  central      lucid    950
```